# Subtraction with while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, subtraction

How i can do subtractions with the while loop? i can do additions, but i can't do subtractions, here is my code:

```
int V, RE=0;
char OP, R;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
printf("Choose an operation (+Addition -Subtraction): ");
scanf("%c", &OP);

setbuf(stdin, NULL);
if (OP=='+') {
    do{
    printf("Type a value or -1 to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &V);
    if (V!=+1)
        RE = RE + V;
    }while(V!=+1);
    printf("Sum: %d \n", RE);
}
else if (OP=='-') {
    do{
    printf("Type a value or 0 to exit: ");
    scanf("%d", &V);
    if (V!=0)
        RE = RE - V;
    }while(V!=0);
    printf("Result: %d \n", RE);
}
else if (OP=='*') {
}
else if (OP=='/') {
}
system("pause");
```

when I execute the code with the values 20 and 10, the program should answer "10" but instead, the program answer me -30, how can I fix that?

Comment: Did you initialize `RE` before addition or subtraction to it?

Comment: yes i initialized re : int V, RE=0;

Comment: @11thSpaceWarrior did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you initialize `RE` to `0`, that's wrong. `RE` should be initialized to the first value `20`. If you initialized `RE` to `0` what are you expecting?

```
RE = 0;
RE = RE - V; // V == 20 -> RE = 0 - 20   = -20;
RE = RE - V; // V == 10 -> RE = -20 - 10 = -30
```

if you instead try this,

```
printf("Type a value or press 0 to exit: ");    
scanf("%d", &RE);
if (RE != 0)
{
    do {
        printf("Type a value or press 0 to exit: ");    
        scanf("%d", &V);
        if (V != 0)
            RE = RE - V;
    } while (V != 0);
    printf("Result: %d \n", RE);
}
```

it will give you the correct result.

Also, since `0` is a number, the condition to exit the loop, is not very good, you should instead check the result of `scanf()`.

```
printf("Type a value or q to exit: ");    
if (scanf("%d", &RE) == 1)
{
    int count;
    do {
        printf("Type a value or q to exit: ");    
        count = scanf("%d", &V);
        if (count == 1)
            RE = RE - V;
    } while (count == 1);
    printf("Result: %d \n", RE);
 }
```

this will exit on any non numeric input, but you get the point I suppose.

Also with your code as is, undefined behavior will occure if invalid input is entered, because the value you are trying to read might not get initialized.

**Note**: you can use a switch if you're allowed to, like

```
switch (OP)
{
case '+':
    /* operate here */
    break;
case '-':
    /* operate here */
    break;
case '*':
    /* operate here */
    break;
case '/':
    /* operate here */
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I can see now :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Subtraction logic. When you enter 20 it is stored in RE as a negative number because

```
RE = RE - V; and RE is zero in the first iteration.
```

When you enter the second number the above expression becomes

```
RE = -20 -10 which is -30;
```

If you are trying to subtract 2 numbers then read the two numbers  using `scanf` first and then do the math

```
RE = NUM1-NUM2;
```